Combining Spring Boot JPA with entity graph
I am using Spring Boot JPA to pull employee details. My employee entity looks like below:
Employee.java
public class Employee {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", referencedColumnName = "DEPT_ID")
   private Department department;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "ADD_ID", referencedColumnName = "ADD_ID")
   private Address address;
}

In Employee Repo, when I tried List<Employee> findAll() method, it goes into N+1 problem and to tackle it, I tried with Entity Graph, which solved the issue. But my repository method looks like below,
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"department", "address"})
List<Employee> findByDepartmentActiveIndOrderByAddressCity(String activeInd);

with above repository method I am able to achieve what is required but the method name is big. Is there way to combine entity graph and Jpa specification. I tried basic JPA Specification joining Department and Address entities but it gives me N+1 issue. Is there a better approach or is there a way to combine entity graph with specification?

You can join using Specification:
public static Specification<Employee> hasDepartmentWithActiveInd(String activeInd) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join<Department, Employee> employeesDepartment = root.join("departments");
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(employeesDepartment.get("activeInd"), activeInd);
    };
}

If you want to go advanced and make the entity graph dynamic during runtime, then try this library - https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph

this gives me N+1 issue which is the reason I tried with Entity graph.

This should run only one join
